# C#: Adding text to where cursor is

Tags: c#, wpf

i want to handle the tab keypress in such a way that

if there is no selected text, add 4 spaces at cursor position. if there is selected text, i want to add 4 spaces at the start of each selected lines. something like what ide's like visual studio does. how do i do this?

i am using WPF/C#

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: In what type of application do you want to handle a keypress? The C# language is used all over the place: WPF, Windows Forms, Silverlight, Console, to name a few examples.  Your question is likely more relevant to a specific platform than to a specific language.

Comment: I'm looking my magic cristal ball, I think you're trying to use a multiline texbox, a richtextbox or something like this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is for WPF:

```
textBox.AcceptsReturn = true;
textBox.AcceptsTab = false;
textBox.KeyDown += OnTextBoxKeyDown;
...

private void OnTextBoxKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key != Key.Tab)
        return;

    string tabReplacement = new string(' ', 4);
    string selectedTextReplacement = tabReplacement +
        textBox.SelectedText.Replace(Environment.NewLine, Environment.NewLine + tabReplacement);

    int selectionStart = textBox.SelectionStart;
    textBox.Text = textBox.Text.Remove(selectionStart, textBox.SelectionLength)
                               .Insert(selectionStart, selectedTextReplacement);

    e.Handled = true; // to prevent loss of focus
}
```

Comment: how can i detect a key combination? eg. Shift+Tab?

Comment: @jiewmeng: System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.Modifiers. Check my answer to your question: "How can i modify selected text/wrap content etc?"